# Do I need to insulate my basement?

Tags: insulation, basement

I am currently finishing my basement and wondering if I need to insulate my basement. I have already framed all the walls.  I have a below grade basement and the temp is pretty consistent. Local code does not require insulation or vapor barrier. My plan was to run my electrical and throw up the drywall. I do not plan on drywalling the ceiling, I plan on keeping it exposed. Is it worth the time and money to insulate? I have read several articles on whether to insulate or not and they all contradict one another.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are you located, and what is your climate like? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Insulated my basement ceiling. Nothing fancy, it was R-13 rockwool batt. My main focus for it was sound deadening moreso than temperature control.  One thing you would have to consider is any lights you have in the ceiling and whether or not they're rating to have insulation around them.

Comment: Are you in a heating or cooling climate?

Comment: I think they contradict each other because the ground temp is fairly consistent. I have spent a bunch insulating a basement to find no change in the heating cost with comparable winter months. It may have “felt warmer” faster but not much different to another house that I just had an air space behind furring strips. After purchasing houses that the insulation had gotten wet and everything had to be pulled out I would go with no insulation and just a small air space (not glued to the wall as I have found that also).  I leave this as a comment as it is opinion after owning and remodeling several

Comment: @EdBeal, sounds like a reasonable approach. This definitely depends on the location. The investment payback for insulation I'm sure varies from Alabama to Michigan.

Comment: I would agree the first home with a basement I purchased was in Ohio that was the one I finished out and saw no change in the power bill but I only lived there for 3 years, one of the ones that I ended up gutting was in in California (not as many basements there or in that area) I have had several more up in Oregon and have just used furring spaces for full disclosure on the climate zones I have had basements.